# Use eclim completion on Tab

Tags: eclipse, vim, autocomplete, vim-plugin, eclim

Is it possible to use eclims completion on <kbd>TAB</kbd>? Right now I managed to use <kbd>TAB</kbd> when there is a `.` with `let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = 'context'`. But I would like to let eclim take over the whole completion at all times.

Answer (score 0):

This should do

`let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "<c-x><c-u>"`